# Get image height and width of image stored on Amazon S3

Tags: image, amazon-s3, information-retrieval

I plan to store images on Amazon S3 how to retrieve from Amazon S3 :

- file size
- image height
- image width ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Getting the file size is possible by reading the `Content-Length` response header to a simple `HEAD` request for your file. Maybe your client can help you with this query. More info on the [S3 API docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html).

Amazon S3 just provides you with storage, (almost) nothing more. Image dimensions are not accessible through the API. You have to get the whole file, and calculate its dimensions yourself. I'd advise you to store this information in the database when uploading the files to S3, if applicable.

Answer (score 36):

You can store image dimensions in user-defined metadata when uploading your images and later read this data using REST API.

Refer to this page for more information about user-defined metadata: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, rather than storing in database. there's a catch: once a file is upload to amazon, the metadata cannot be changed. so there is no retro-active solution. one would have to duplicate the file.

Comment: That's kind of stupid as you can modify the metadata in the S3 web backend - so why don't they support it in the API? Dumb dumb dumb

Answer (score -1):

On Node, it can be really easy using [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) coupled with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

```js
async function getSize(imageUrl) {
  const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
  const buffer = await response.buffer();
  return imageSize(buffer);
}
```

Comment: But wouldnt that mean that the backend would download the image? and therefore have a slower response?